# R.java package name is not as the main package name

Tags: android, eclipse, r.java-file

I have a problem that my R.java package name is not the same as my main package name.

I tried to rename R.java package name but when i do it, eclipse auto generate another

package with the old R.java package name.

I tried to disable Build Automaticly for R.java but then i cant generate new R.java for my app.

I think that this missmatch in package name is causing me some crashes in my app.

Added srceen shot.

[image]

Comment: `import com.whatever.your.packagename.in.manifest.is.R;` works perfectly fine. Check that you don't import `android.R` though since that can lead to errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`R.java`'s package name is dependent on your [AndroidManifest.xml's `package` element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html). Change that to whatever you want and rebuild your project.